# boosting function in adabag in R package runs too long

Tags: r

```
require(adabag)    
data(diamonds)
ind = sample(2, nrow(iris), replace = T, prob = c(0.8, 0.2))
train = diamonds[ind==1,]
test = diamonds[ind==2,]
boost = boosting(cut ~ carat + price, data = diamonds, boos = T, mfinal = 5)
```

This is my first time to use `adabag` package, and I want to know is it normal for the code in last line to run over 1 hr? There are 37766 rows in `train`.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Why not develop your model based on the training set you've defined?  `boost = boosting(cut ~ carat + price, data = train, boos = T, mfinal = 5)`